# Error web service expert system "drools"

Tags: eclipse, web-services, drools

I have an error when I created a web service to my program
my program called an expert system "drools" which I think is the problem.
I tried a web service with simple program "without expert system" he is walking normally

```
Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/drools/event/KnowledgeRuntimeEventManager; nested exception is: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/drools/event/KnowledgeRuntimeEventManager Message: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/drools/event/KnowledgeRuntimeEventManager; nested exception is: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/drools/event/KnowledgeRuntimeEventManager
```

Comment: From the tremendous amount of information you've provided I can only say that the program throwing the exception either misses some knowledge-api-5.Y.Z.Final.jar or kie-internal-6.X.Z.Final.jar jar file in its classpath.

Comment: Thank you @laune , these errors are gone but seemed other errors

Comment: <Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session; nested exception is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session Message: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session; nested exception is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session >

Comment: You might need another jar...